XGBoost F1 score impovement methods for multi class classification
I am building a multiclass classification (5 classes) using XGBoost. Currently using 56 features for 1.6 million customer base having balanced classes.
The overall accuracy is 83%, F1 score is 0.81, and AUC > 0.90. How to improve the accuracy?
I have already tested below:
No missing value 
Cross-validation 
outlier treatment 
logistic and random forest (XGBoost is giving better results) 
correlation 
hyperparameter tuned and below are the final params: 
model = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax', 
                          num_class=5,
                          eval_metric='mlogloss',
                          max_depth=6,
                          eta=0.3,
                          seed=42
                         )

Any help to further improve accuracy will be much appreciated.

Do better feature engineering.

Note that accuracy, F1 etc. all have major issues. Yes, even in the "balanced" case. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352
